# Looking for options for PHP Debugging

Tags: php, debugging, ide

I am looking for PHP debug options. I know there is xDebug and I know it is a good tool, but the learning curve is a bit too steep and long for me at the moment. Perhaps I will learn it in the future..

For now, I am looking for a debug tool like the ones found in visual studio suite. 
My main problem is this: Suppose I am working on a framework, then the URL that is shown does not really give too many clues to which file is currently being executed, for instance.

Anyone with experience working with debug tools? Any input is appreciated!

Comment: A steep [learning curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_curve) is good. It means you learn a lot with relatively little effort.

Comment: "If you understood what someone said, then said it right - doesn't matter grammar or spelling or usage. Language is meant to communicate and the person has just done that" says Noam Chomsky :)

Comment: "To minimize the probability of misunderstanding, it is wise to adhrere to well established standards in grammar and spelling and usage" says Oswald :)

Comment: Personally, between Oswald and Chomsky? I would go with Chomsky ;-)

Comment: Well, so would I. Nevertheless, I think Oswald has some mighty good words to say.

Comment: ha ha Oswald does have some might good words to say about himself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [FirePHP](http://firephp.org/) - a Firefox extension which works with Firebug (a great JavaScript debugging tool for Firefox - see https://getfirebug.com/). It takes a little work to set up, but once active it's great for debugging using the Firebug extension tools which includes the ability to set breakpoints etc.

Comment: That is a very good suggestion, I will definitely try it!

Comment: It's true that with this approach, you only get breakpoints, watch expressions etc. with the JavaScript code. FirePHP does only allow you to get PHP execution information which in itself is pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow a tutorial it is actually pretty easy to get debug working in eclipse. And it speeds up your development a lot. I suggest you try. FirePhp is very good for getting execution information, but you can not set breakponts, watch expressions, etc.

You can find a lot of tutorials, like this:
http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/articles/debugger/os-php-eclipse-pdt-debug-pdf.pdf

I also suggest you have a look at:
http://www.phpeclipse.com/

It might take a bit of trial and error but once you get it it will be yours forever and you will have a coding environment  similar to the visual studio suites, but free :)